# window.localStorage function not working on API Routing NextJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, window

How to can use window syntax on API Route NextJS?

```
export async function POST(request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse<DataResponse>) {
    const dataReq = await request.json();
    window.localStorage('cachestore', JSON.stringify(dataReq));
}
```

The function window on POST or GET in the Next JS Routing API does not work. However, on a regular page it can run using the `useEffect()=>{}` function. How can I make it work well when accessing the /api/page page?

Comment: Can you please provide a detailed description of your issue? It's really hard to tell you WHY something is wrong without knowing WHAT is wrong

Comment: window object is only available for browser (client side) not the server where the api routes run. You can send the json back to the client side and set it to localstorage from there